# .net OpenSearch Library

Tags: .net, opensearch

All, is a .net library that can take a result set and generate a open search feed? Also, how much work is involved to create one? It would be great if you can direct me to some online resources.

Thanks.

**EDIT**: I am not looking for a search engine. I would like to expose a result set to another website which supports Open Search. When a user types in a keyword in the other website, the site will send a request to my system and I will return a result set based on that keyword in a format which meets the Open Search standard.

Answer (score 0):

you mean something like Lucene? "Apache Lucene(TM) is a high-performance, full-featured text search engine library written entirely in Java. It is a technology suitable for nearly any application that requires full-text search, especially cross-platform."  ( http://lucene.apache.org/java/docs/index.html)

here is a .net port

http://incubator.apache.org/lucene.net/

Comment: I am not looking for a search engine, such as lucene. Please see my edited post.